# Get the group of Object list

Tags: java, collections

I have a Java class called a truck and another class called truckparts. I want to get the collection of output in the bellowed specified format. I have tried with the collection which does not work for me and give me not expected result.

```
public class Truck {
    private String name;
    private int qty;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private List<Integer> platIds = new ArrayList<>();
    // Constructor and getters and setters
```

I have another class:

```
public class TruckParts {
    private Integer id;
    private String namepart;
    private int qtypart;
    private BigDecimal pricepart;
    private Truck truck = new Truck();
    // Constructor and getters and setters
```

I have received an Input in the form of a list of objects like below:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "namepart":"val",
    "qtypart":"fg",
    "pricepart":120,
    "name":"valasdhjk",
    "qty" :"sdfg",
    "price":123,
    "partid":1
   },
   {
    "id": 1,
    "namepart":"val",
    "qtypart":"fg",
    "pricepart":120,
    "name":"valasdhjk",
    "qty" :"sdfg",
    "price":123,
    "partid": 1
   },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "namepart":"val",
    "qtypart":"fg",
    "pricepart":120,
    "name":"valasdhjk",
    "qty" :"sdfg",
    "price":123,
    "partid":1
   },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "namepart":"val",
    "qtypart":"fg",
    "pricepart":120,
    "name":"valasdhjk",
    "qty" :"sdfg",
    "price":123,
    "partid":2
   }
]
```

Now I want this output to convert into this form:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "namepart":"val",
    "qtypart":"fg",
    "pricepart":120,
    "truck":{
            "name":"valasdhjk",
            "qty" :"sdfg",
            "price":123,
            "partids":[1,2]
     }

   },

   {
    "id": 2,
    "namepart":"val",
    "qtypart":"fg",
    "pricepart":120,
    "truck:"{
          "name":"valasdhjk",
          "qty" :"sdfg",
          "price":123,
          "partids":[1,2]
     }
   }
]
```

I have tried with the map.

```
 Map<BigDecimal, List<TruckParts>> groupByid = 
        items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TruckParts::getId));
```

but it seems this is not what I am looking for. Can someone tell me the best way to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going in the right direction with this:

```
 Map<BigDecimal, List<TruckParts>> groupById = 
        items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TruckParts::getId));
```

With that `Map<BigDecimal, List<TruckParts>>`, you can map each entry into a `Truck` object:

```
groupById.entrySet().stream().map(x -> {
    // assuming your constructor's parameters go in the order of name, qty, price, platIds
    return new Truck(x.getValue().get(0).getNamePart(), 
              x.getValue().get(0).getQtyPart(), 
              x.getValue().get(0).getPricePart(),
              x.getValue().stream().map(TruckPart::getPartId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
})
```

Comment: it is asking for return statement

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer oops! Should be fixed now.

Comment: I am facing something different problem, can u please help me with this , may be in private chat if u have time

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer if my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it. If you have another problem, you can ask another question.

Comment: how to print this values using System.out.println